# Copy Salesforce standard auto increment field to custom field

Tags: custom-field, leads, clone

I'm trying to copy the 'Lead ID' field that's auto generated by Salesforce into a custom field. I'm unable to view this particular field under Leads but its coming up in reports. Is there a way to clone this ID field to a custom field.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to do this but a simple formula field shall suffice

```
Id18__c
```

with formula =

```
CASESAFEID(Id)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. CASESAFEID(Id) was adding extra three characters at the end and then i realized that i could update the formula to just 'Id'

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the 18 character ID.  The 15 character and 18 character ID point at the same record.